# identifying an i element in css properties

Tags: html, css, element

I want to change the position of an i element which is an icon. I have tried including it's class and changing the position but it didn't seem to work, I then included it in a span element and it still doesn't seem to identify the element neither in positioning or other properties.

the element structure:

```css
.map {
  object-position: top;
  size: 10px;
}

.fa-map-marker {
  object-position: top;
  size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Fontawesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">


<!-- Body -->
<span class="map" onclick="location.href='#';" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="font-size:48px;color:red"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Do you mean the CSS property size which doesn’t seem relevant here. How about width and/height?

Answer (score 1):

```
.fa-map-marker {
 position: absolute;
 left:20px;
 /*right: 10px;*/
```

}

Try this For Changing the of icon And also if you want to move it on right jus the right property and remove the left one.

Comment: no the size does not relate to the icon also the height & weight Just use the font size to increase the size of icons

Answer (score 0):

### Dimensions

**`size` does not exist**

**Use `height` and `width`**

Normally a block-level (`display: block`) element like a `<div>` should be used as a container -- a `<span>` (`display: inline`) is formless, giving an element *"size"* (`height` and `width`) would work on blocks not inline. Any element can be a block by assigning `display:block` if you have your heart set on using a `<span>`.

### Position

**`top` does not work on static elements**

Assign `position`: `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed`, or `sticky` in order to
position elements `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom`.

### Font Icons

Font-Awesome is a collection of font characters and SVG. Just like the text you see before you, the icons are just another character. Here are some CSS properties that are used on fonts:

- `font-size`
- `font-weight`
- `color`

You should read:

- [W3School CSS Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/)
- [MDN CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

```css
html {
  font: 300 2vmax Consolas;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.map {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 90vw;
  min-height: 93vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: url(https://media.hswstatic.com/eyJidWNrZXQiOiJjb250ZW50Lmhzd3N0YXRpYy5jb20iLCJrZXkiOiJnaWZcL21hcHMuanBnIiwiZWRpdHMiOnsicmVzaXplIjp7IndpZHRoIjo4Mjh9LCJ0b0Zvcm1hdCI6ImF2aWYifX0=) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

#a {
  top: 35vh;
  left: 28.75vw;
  color: red;
}

#b {
  top: 21vh;
  right: 28.75vw;
  color: lime;
}

#c {
  top: 61vh;
  left: 50vw;
  color: blue;
}

.fa-fighter-jet {
  top: 68vh;
  right: 56vw;
  color: black;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.fa-plane {
  top: 37vh;
  left: 23vw;
  color: magenta;
  transform: rotate(205deg);
}
```

```html
<!-- Fontawesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">

<a class="map" href='#'>
  <i id='a' class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
  <i id='b' class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-plane"></i>
  <i id='c' class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-fighter-jet"></i>
</a>
```